# Insert code sample into a Google Groups post

Tags: google-groups

I'd like to add the following code sample to Google Groups:

```
<html>
    <script type = "text/javascript">
        var async = require("async");
    </script>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

How can I insert source code into Google groups like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Direct copy+paste will work, but if you want to make it look like code you'll have to

- Indent the code using the indent button
- Select the code block and change the font
- Select the code block & apply relevant colour.

[image]

All these should be possible from the Web UI

Comment: I don't know how you get that menu - I don't see an indent menu option

Answer (score 0):

I use the Chrome/Firefox/etc. add-on [Markdown Here](https://markdown-here.com/) . It works fine with google groups.